# If there is a software for Mac similar to WinSCP on Windows?

Tags: linux, osx, virtual-machine

I use VMware Fusion created a VM(Linux) in my Mac, but I don't know how to delivery the data from my Mac to the VM.

If the VM is on the Windows I can use the WinSCP to load data to it, but how can I load data to VM from Mac?

Some friend can recommend me a software to load data to Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount a directory (or drive) of VM on your Mac or vice-versa with [NFS](http://blog.fosketts.net/2015/03/20/using-nfs-to-share-data-between-unix-and-mac-os-x/), for example:

### On Linux:

First install (and start) NFS on your linux VM, if your distro is debian based:

```
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
sudo systemctl nfs-kernel-server start
```

1) Create user account, in this example, let's set the user and group ID to 5000

```
useradd -u 5000 macusers
```

2) Set password for NFS user account:

```
# passwd macusers
```

3) Edit the exports file, here we use vim:

```
# vim /etc/exports
```

4) Add the following line (fix to your context):

```
/home/user/share 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

5) Save and exit.

6) Set permission to exports:

```
chown -R macuser:macuser /home/user/share
```

### Enable NFS on OS X

1) On a terminal window, start the NFS service (enter your password, if necessary):

```
# sudo nfs start
```

2) Close the terminal window.

### Launch Connect to server:

1) Press Command+K to launch Connect to Server.

2) In the server address field enter nfs:// define the network protocol for CIFS and then enter the IP address of the server with the export path

```
nfs://192.168.5.3/home/user/share
```

3) Click connect to connect to share.

[See this link for more detail.](http://blog.fosketts.net/2015/03/20/using-nfs-to-share-data-between-unix-and-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 0):

At last, I find the FTP tool for mac:

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org)

Answer (score 0):

muCommander has two-tabs interface similar to WinSCP and AFAIK can copy files over ssh in the same way.